# How to automatically save IDE layout in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

We are having an issue in Delphi XE2 with the automated saving of the desktop layout. Under environment options I do have the **Autosave options - Project Desktop** checked. However, changes to the layout of the desktop are not being saved and restored each time the IDE is launched.

The workaround we have in place is to use a custom destkop layout under View | Desktops. This requires us to manually save this layout each time we make a change.

Is there another setting that needs to be enabled in order for the desktop layout (window size, position, toolbar settings, etc) to persist from session to session without requiring the developer to manually save this layout?

Comment: Thanks Ken. That's what we are doing now. I guess I must have misunderstood the auto save option for the project desktop. It seemed to me that if checked it would automatically save the last layout either when the project was saved or on a periodic basis. What's its purpose if it doesn't do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is to configure a custom desktop, and then save it. You can have multiple desktops (eg., normal and debug, among others) and easily switch between them using the "Desktop SpeedSetting" combobox (and associated toolbuttons) in the main menu/toolbar of the IDE. Saving is as easy as clicking the Save button and either accepting the current name or providing a new name, and switching is choosing a named desktop from the combobox.

"Autosave project desktop" saves the open files in the code editor, and whether you're on the design or code page for each form. It also saves the build configuration (debug or release). It will save which of the selected stored desktop layout you've chosen, but not any changes to that desktop layout.